# Why isn't there IntStream.flatMapToObj()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Stream<Object> stream = IntStream.of(...)
        .flatMapToObj(i -> getStreamOfObjects(i));
```

Unfortunately, `IntStream.flatMapToObj()` doesn't exist, even in Java 9.

1. Why was it left out?
2. What's a recommended workaround?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Why was it was left out?

The API provides reusable building blocks. The relevant building blocks here are `IntStream`, `mapToObj`, `flatMap`. From these you can achieve what you want: map an in stream to objects, and then get a flat map. Providing permutations of building blocks would not be practical, and harder to extend.

> What's a recommended workaround?

As hinted earlier, use the available building blocks (`mapToObj` + `flatMap`):

```
Stream<Object> stream = IntStream.of(...)
    .mapToObj(i -> Stream.of(...))
    .flatMap(...);
```

Comment: Good answer. I think I subconsciously assumed `IntStream.flatMapToObj()` was as necessary as `Stream.flatMapToInt()`, but that's obviously not the case.

Comment: this `.flatMap(...)` should probably be `.flatMap(Function.identity())` since you have already mapped to Streams with mapToObj

Comment: I'm not that convinced by this - in the API we're given the `.boxed()` method, which should eliminate the need for `.mapToObj(...)` because all can be rewritten to `.boxed().map(...)`. It seems inconsistent therefore to have provided `.mapToObj()` (`.boxed().map(...)`) but not `.flatMapToObj()` (`.boxed().flatMap()`).

Comment: @MrPotes `.boxed().map(...)` is not the same as `.mapToObj(...)`, because boxing is not exactly free. In this example, if you have a function that returns a stream for a primitive `int`, then boxing the `int` will be a waste, and could even lead to performance issues. In other words, `mapToObj` is necessary due to primitive types in Java. (Sad and ugly but true.)

Comment: Yes, true, hadn't thought of the cost of boxing :)

Comment: @janos Wait that doesn't make sense, you're moving the goalposts. Surely the same logic would still apply. If boxing isn't "free", then surely neither is an additional ```flatMap(Function::Identity)```? And then not having ```flatMapToObj()``` is an oversight?

Answer (score 15):

Using a boxed stream would work if you don't mind the cost of boxing each `int` value.

```
Stream<Object> stream = IntStream.of(...).boxed().flatMap(i -> getStreamOfObjects(i));
```

Answer (score 12):

Just write

```
IntStream.of(...)
        .mapToObj(i -> getStreamOfObjects(i))
        .flatMap(stream -> stream)
```

Comment: just as note, you can use  `Function.identity()` instead of `stream -> stream`