# compile time: no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The following statement, although nonsensical, appears syntactically sound.

```
final Stream<LongStream> foobar = IntStream.empty()
    .flatMap(x -> IntStream.empty()
        .mapToObj(y -> IntStream.empty()
            .mapToLong(z -> 1))); //compilation error here on `z -> 1`
```

However it does not compile, returning:

> java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
>       no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that java.util.stream.Stream conforms to java.util.stream.IntStream

However if you delay the flatmap, everything works fine:

```
final Stream<LongStream> foobar = IntStream.empty()
    .mapToObj(x -> IntStream.empty()
        .mapToObj(y -> IntStream.empty()
            .mapToLong(z -> 1)))
    .flatMap(x -> x);
```

What is the difference between `.mapToObj(..).flatMap(..)` and just `.flatMap(..)`? Is there someway to eliminate the extra flatmap call?

Comment: This question shows why lambdas inside lambdas inside lambdas are a terrible idea.

Comment: Related: [Why isn't there `IntStream.flatMapToObj()`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41295766/5743988)

Comment: @Joe C: I have used “lambdas inside lambdas inside lambdas” without problems and if they fit into the actual problem, there is no reason to avoid them. While current IDEs struggle while you are typing them, they work smoothly once the (correct) code has been written.

Comment: "there is no reason to avoid them" - well, besides maintainability.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.mapToObj(..).flatMap(..)` and `.flatMap(..)` expect completely different signatures.

`.mapToObj(..).flatMap(..)` expects an `int -> Object` function, and an `Object -> Stream<?>` function.

`.flatMap(..)` expects an `int -> IntStream` function.

If you break down your code, you're passing an `int -> Stream<LongStream>` function, which isn't compatible with an `int -> IntStream` function.

You would have the [same error](https://ideone.com/9T24h2) with this simplified code:

```
IntStream.empty().flatMap(x -> Stream.of(LongStream.empty()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored your method to break down what it's doing:

```
IntFunction<LongStream> f1 = y -> IntStream.empty().mapToLong(z -> 1);
IntFunction<LongStream> f2 = x -> IntStream.empty().mapToObj(f1);
final Stream<LongStream> foobar = IntStream.empty().flatMap(f2);
```

We have two things wrong here:

The lambda on line 2 does not return a `LongStream`, but rather a `Stream<LongStream>`, as we are converting each `int` in our stream to a `LongStream`.  If you intend for it to be a single `LongStream`, you need to do a `flatMapToLong`.

The `flatMap` on line 3 expects an `int -> int` function, which yours is not.  However, you can use `mapToObj` instead, which takes the method that you're providing it.

So the corrected method would be:

```
IntFunction<LongStream> f1 = y -> IntStream.empty().mapToLong(z -> 1);
IntFunction<LongStream> f2 = x -> IntStream.empty().mapToObj(f1).flatMapToLong(i -> i);
final Stream<LongStream> foobar = IntStream.empty().mapToObj(f2);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be `IntFunction<Stream<LongStream>>`? I'm not sure how you arrived at those statements from the question, only to refute your own statements. Also, `flatMap` expects an `int -> IntStream` function.

Comment: If it's the first set of statements you're referring to, this is just me using the refactor function in my IDE.

Comment: @4castle The expression as a whole is self-contradictory, therefore there is freedom of choice on how to infer arguments and where to imagine "the" error.

Comment: There really aren't very many type inferences going on in this code, because `IntStream` doesn't use wildcards for its method signatures. Read the code carefully, and there is only one way it can be interpreted.