# Stream / IntRange over 2D coordinates?

Tags: java, coordinates, java-stream

I have the following classes:

```
public class Rectangle
{
   public int width, height;
   public Point start;

   public Rectangle(Point start, int width, int height)
   {
      this.start = start;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
   }
}

public class Point
{
   public int x, y;

   public Point(int x, int y)
   {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}
```

I want to make a method of the Rectangle class such that a Java 8 `Stream` of type `Point` is returned where it would stream index locations inside the rectangle. Ex.

```
// This is inside the rectangle class.
public Stream<Point> stream(int hstep, int vstep)
{
   // if the rectangle started at 0,0
   // and had a width and height of 100
   // and hstep and vstep were both 1
   // then the returned stream would be
   // 0,0 -> 1,0 -> 2,0 -> ... -> 100,0 -> 0,1 -> 1,1 -> ...

   // If vstep was 5 and h step was 25 it would return
   // 0,0 -> 25,0 -> 50,0 -> 75,0 -> 100,0 -> 0,5 -> 25,5 -> ...

   return ...
}
```

I've used `IntStream` a lot, `map`, `filter`, etc but this is much more complicated then anything I've ever tried. I have no idea how I would do something like that. Can someone steer me int he right direction?

Comment: If the rectangle has a width of 100, `100,0` shouldn't be a valid point.

Comment: sorry, you are correct that's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested `IntStream` to generate each `Point`, then flatten the resulting stream:

```
public Stream<Point> stream(int hstep, int vstep) {
    return IntStream.range(0, height / vstep)
            .mapToObj(y -> IntStream.range(0, width / hstep)
                    .mapToObj(x -> new Point(start.x + x * hstep, start.y + y * vstep)))
            .flatMap(Function.identity());
}
```

Comment: Wow... what a solution. That is insane. Thank you so much. Can you explain why `.flatMap` is needed at the end and what `Function.identity()` does?

Comment: @Hatefiend `flatMap()` maps each element to its own stream and then flattens the result into one stream. Since the previous operation returned `Stream<Stream<Point>>`, all we need to do is map each element to itself, which is accomplished by `Function.identity()`, equivalent to `stream -> stream`.

Comment: Wow. Java 8 streams are amazing

Comment: Or, in other words, in a perfect world, there was a method `flatMapToObj` in `IntStream`, just like there is a `flatMapToInt` in `Stream`. Then, we would use `flatMapToObj(function)` here, but since we can’t, we use `mapToObj(function).flatMap(Function.identity())` instead.

Comment: @Holger Yup, I actually [asked about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41295766/1553851) a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iterate(...)` with `limit(...)` for generating `x` and `y`.
Then you combine both streams and create the `Point` with `flatMap(...)` and `map(...)`

```
public Stream<Point> stream(int hstep, int vstep) {
    return Stream.iterate(this.start.x, s-> s + hstep).
            limit(this.width / hstep).
            flatMap(x-> Stream.iterate(this.start.y, s-> s + vstep).
                    limit(this.height / vstep).map(y-> new Point(x, y)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it.

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Rectangle
{
    public int width, height;
    public Point start;

    public Rectangle(Point start, int width, int height)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Stream<Point> stream(int hstep, int vstep)
    {
        int hSteps = 1 + ((width - 1) / hstep);
        int vSteps = 1 + ((height - 1) / vstep);
        int numPoints = hSteps * vSteps;

        return Stream.generate(new Supplier<Point>()
        { 
            int origStartX = start.x;
            int origWidth = width;

            int x = start.x;
            int y = start.y;

            @Override
            public Point get()
            {
                Point pt = new Point(x, y);

                x += hstep;
                if (x >= origWidth)
                {
                    x = origStartX;
                    y += vstep;
                }

                return pt;
            }
        }).limit(numPoints);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), 100, 100);

        Stream<Point> s = r.stream(25, 5);
        s.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

public class Point
{
  public int x, y;

  public Point(int x, int y)
  {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
     return String.format("(%d, %d)", x, y);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
(0, 0)
(25, 0)
(50, 0)
(75, 0)
(0, 5)
(25, 5)
(50, 5)
(75, 5)
.
.
<snip>
.
.
(0, 90)
(25, 90)
(50, 90)
(75, 90)
(0, 95)
(25, 95)
(50, 95)
(75, 95)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a stream of one type and converting it into a stream of points. This should get you started:

```
return IntStream.range(0, width * height)
    .mapToObj(i -> new Point(i % width, i / width));
```

It doesn't handle `hstep` and `vstep`. See if you can figure out how to add those to the mix.